# new MAMP project goes to > db > mysql57 instead of > htdocs on macOS Monterey V12.2.1

Tags: wordpress, macos, mamp

goal is to create new wordpress site on mamp (as I did many times before); tried to change ports and root directory, doesn't work. uninstalled mamp and installed mamp new, still doesn't work.
tried xamp, DIVI theme doesn´t work well so back to mamp.

does anyone know why it doesn't work?